# terraform get index value from the list

Tags: terraform, hcl

How to assign index value to terraform variable

lets say:

my example input looks,
terraform.tfvars.json:

```
{
    "resource_groups": [
        {
            "name_suffix": "AI",
            "location": "westus2",
            "is_default": false
        },
        {
            "name_suffix": "Montoring",
            "location": "westus2",
            "is_default": false
        },
        {
            "name_suffix": "Base",
            "location": "westus2",
            "is_default": false
        },
        {
            "name_suffix": "Core",
            "location": "westus2",
            "is_default": true
        }

    ]
}
```

main.tf

```
 locals {
 # I tried like 

 default_rg_index = [for rg, index in var.resource_groups: index if try(rg.is_default, false) == true]
}
```

I am expecting default_rg_index to assign 3, but it is not working

Comment: `[{rg_name: "a", is_default: false, {rg_name: "b", is_default: true}]` is invalid TF code. Can you please provide valid example?

Comment: ok, my inputs in json, let me provide you in hcl

Comment: This is also invalid json.

Comment: I fixed it. I manged to guess what you want.

Comment: just added, full input

Comment: You want to find first true value?

Comment: yes, we allowed only one true value, but if input has multiple true, then first true will be considered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rg, index` should be opposite. You can also make it simpler:

```
default_rg_index = [for index, rg in var.resource_groups: index if rg.is_default]
```

Comment: will it return list type or number type?

Comment: @Vidya List. You can use `default_rg_index[0]` to get the value. Or append [0] to  `[for index, rg in var.resource_groups: index if rg.is_default]`.